# Why is Kafka frequently generate log of configuration follow to periodic (every some minutes)

Tags: java, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

My Application often generates log of configuration follow to periodic (every some minutes). I think it has been restarted but I don't know why is reason? Can you help me ?

```
INFO ConsumerConfig: ConsumerConfig values: 
    auto.commit.interval.ms = 100
    auto.offset.reset = earliest
    bootstrap.servers = [kafka:9092]
    check.crcs = true
    client.id = 
    connections.max.idle.ms = 540000
    enable.auto.commit = false
    exclude.internal.topics = true
    fetch.max.bytes = 52428800
    fetch.max.wait.ms = 500
    fetch.min.bytes = 1
    group.id = mail-service
    heartbeat.interval.ms = 3000
    interceptor.classes = null
    internal.leave.group.on.close = true
    isolation.level = read_uncommitted
    key.deserializer = class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArrayDeserializer
    max.partition.fetch.bytes = 1048576
    max.poll.interval.ms = 300000
    max.poll.records = 500
    metadata.max.age.ms = 300000
    metric.reporters = []
    metrics.num.samples = 2
    metrics.recording.level = INFO
    metrics.sample.window.ms = 30000
    partition.assignment.strategy = [class org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.RangeAssignor]
    receive.buffer.bytes = 65536
    reconnect.backoff.max.ms = 1000
    reconnect.backoff.ms = 50
    request.timeout.ms = 305000
    retry.backoff.ms = 100
```

Comment: Can you show the Kafka consumer code?

Comment: It might be even better to share with us a simple project which exhibits such a behavior.

Comment: Also, can you share more context of log, some more lines above? Or is this the only record that repeats?